# Diagnose React Redux Performance with React.addons.Perf

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to improve the performance of React app that has the following structure:

`List
 + Container
   + Item`

The list show about 100 items and the container is a regular React component (not connected to Redux) and Item is a React comopnent that is `connect` to Redux store.

Using [React Perf](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html) I've found that `Container > Connect(Item)` has `Render count` that is very high and also `Inclusive wasted time` that is very high.

I've try to change `Container` component to extend [`PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) but that did not change the Perf output at all.

**My Question**: if `Item` is wrapped with `connect` is it render PureRenderComponent useless?